# asp.net MVC 5 project using Nlog Methodcall target has no effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nlog

In the ASP.net MVC 5 project, use Nuget to install Nlog, Nlog.config, Nlog.schema Packages.
Target xsi:type="MethodCall" in the NLog.config file

NLog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
  <targets>
    <target name="mc" xsi:type="MethodCall" className="NlogMethodCallWebApp.Models.NLogHelper, NlogMethodCallWebApp" methodName="LogMethod">
      <parameter layout="${longdate}" />
      <parameter layout="${uppercase:${level}}" />
      <parameter layout="${message}" />
    </target>

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace,Debug,Info,Warn,Error,Fatal" writeTo="mc" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Execute Debug HomeController Index Action Method

HomeController.cs

```
using NLog;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace NlogMethodCallWebApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            logger.Trace("This is Trace");
            logger.Debug("This is Debug");
            logger.Info("This is Info");
            logger.Warn("This is Warn");
            logger.Error("This is Error");
            logger.Fatal("This is Fatal");

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

LogMethod set breakpoint in class NLogHelper has no effect

NLogHelper.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace NlogMethodCallWebApp.Models
{
    public class NLogHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// c - NLog
        /// </summary>
        public static void LogMethod(string longdate, string level, string message)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("D:{0} L:{1} M:{2}", longdate, level, message));
        }
    }
}
```

NLog does not execute LogMethod method. Where is the problem?

Comment: Check the internal log for this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loglevel is wrong. 
There a multiple possibilities:

`minlevel="Trace,Debug,Info,Warn,Error,Fatal"`  <-- Yours, that wrong

change to:

```
levels="Trace,Debug,Info,Warn,Error,Fatal"
```

or

```
minlevel="Trace"
```

or you can also use minlevel and maxlevel

Details:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#log-levels

Also check that the assembly is inside your output directory (your project must reference this assembly)